# why the same try catch block have two different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to rollback all statements in the `CATCH` block when the error is encountered in the `TRY` block:

```
BEGIN TRY
    begin transaction

    create table t3(a int )
    insert into t3 values(1)
    insert into t3 values(1,2)  --error occur
    insert into t3 values(3)

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    --just take care of rollback
    IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'in catch,ROLLING BACK';
        ROLLBACK
    END
END CATCH
go
```

At first the error is caught since the PRINT in the `CATCH` block works. However, after several changes back and forth, the error seems not be caught in the `CATCH` any more since no more printing happens.

[image: no printing out]

Therefore, I open a new query and execute the same thing. This time error can be caught again!!

[image: printing out]

Sorry about the big images

Comment: Don't post images of code, just paste the code as text!

Comment: Compile errors aren't generally catchable (except if they happen during a deferred compile or at a child scope)

Comment: I think it is a deferred compile. As it shown, the error is catch to BEGIN CATCH in second one. But in first one, it seems the error is catch by SQL SERVER.

Comment: You cannot rely on the output of the print statement for determining sequence. It can execute in parallel, etc...

Answer (score 2):

When you run this code in a tool like management studio, your transaction is mantained for your SPID (assigned to a query window).

So the *inconsistent reult* issue is because you don't close the transaction on all of your code paths (lets say the rollback dosn't get reached), your transaction is still active the next time you run the script.

If you add `IF @@TRANCOUNT <> 0 rollback transaction` to the begining of your script you will have a consistent output.

Also notice that the `try catch` block is not meant to catch errors at statement compile level.

If you replace your error by a *division by zero* for example (`print 1 / 0`) the catch will work properly.

In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:
>
> Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from
>   running.
>
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object name resolution
> - Errors that occur after compilation because of deferred name resolution.

Comment: The screenshot shows `SET XACT_ABORT ON`. This will terminate the transaction on error.

Comment: Andre,I executed them in two separate query window. I try it again. If I comment off rollback in on query window. Table A was created actually. Then I switch to another query window

Comment: This time, the second query is running forever and even SQL SERVER didn't catch any issue

Comment: I found answer for above issue. Since first query transaction isn't committed and concurrency type of SQL SERVER is set to read committed by default. This type doesn't allow other query to read table in the first query before it is committed.After I set type to read uncommitted. Two query don't have conflict and can operate on the same table

Comment: That's correct, and its a handy way to test concurrency with transactions too.